# I have some functionality questions on the collapse feature in VF -- can't find much documentation

Tags: visualforce

Whenever I try searching for documentation on the collapse feature for VF page sections, all I find are 4+ year old forums of people writing custom classes and methods to handle this alternatively. I'm assuming this may be a relatively new feature, because I just thought to try collapsible = 'true' inline, and lo and behold, it did the trick.

Does anybody have any documentation on this? I would love to be directed. Otherwise, maybe I can get some answers from the community.

I want a section at the bottom of a form to only be available if a part on the top is filled out. I'm wondering if there is some sort of feature that sets a section to collapsed, toggled by some other variable or section. I also am wondering if there is a way that sets the default to collapsed vs. ...not collapsed. I'm sure there are ways I could figure out how to get this effect with work arounds, but if there are more clear-cut, straightforward ways to toggle sections this way, I always prefer to know best practice whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collapsing feature has been present since version 11.0 (according to the documentation), in other words, since Visualforce was still a beta version. You can see the list of attributes available in [apex:pageBlockSection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm). This is normally true by default. There is no way to specify if a section is collapsed by default, however. There is a hack you can do, outlined in [000181821](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181821&language=en_US). Basically, you perform some JavaScript after the page loads, like so:

```
<script> twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]) 
</script>
```

---

Functional Example:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="true" title="Hello">
            Hello
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <script>
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.hideListButton"), function(v) { v.click() })
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hello -- thank you for your help. However, I'm not seeing how that piece of code is supposed to set it to collapse by default. It doesn't work, and I can't quite see how it would. Suggestions?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis This code assumes that your page block has an "id" of "block1", and your section has an "id" of "section1". You'll want to match the names of the elements to your code. Read 000181821 for the example markup that goes with this script.

Comment: I of course matched the ID names I had -- it still does not do what I'd like. What is the 'img' part of it?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Did you include a "title" attribute? It won't twisty without it.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis I've added a functional example that I whipped up to get you started.